# BitVecVal not found as an attribute to z3

Tags: python, z3, smt, z3py

I am trying to use Python API of `z3`, one of the more popular SMT solvers, to create an SMT instance. To begin, I would like to create four bit vectors with two bits and values ranging from zero to three. My initialization code in Python is the following:

```
import z3

NONE = z3.BitVecVal(0, 2)
A    = z3.BitVecVal(1, 2)
B    = z3.BitVecVal(2, 2)
C    = z3.BitVecVal(3, 2)
```

But I encountered this error when running the Python file:
`AttributeError: module 'z3' has no attribute 'BitVecVal'`. I looked up `BitVecVal` and it is a valid instance of `z3`, shown [here](https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a74d306d60d4cc4432907f58306b41686). Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your program. I added a print version at the beginning and a print statement at the end:

```py
import z3

print z3.get_version_string()

NONE = z3.BitVecVal(0, 2)
A    = z3.BitVecVal(1, 2)
B    = z3.BitVecVal(2, 2)
C    = z3.BitVecVal(3, 2)

print  NONE, A, B, C
```

And I get:

```
4.8.8
0 1 2 3
```

This suggests your installation is somehow busted. Your best bet might be to reinstall from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem in Pycharm IDE (when I only install z3 from file->setting-> Project Interpreter -> add )
But after the I install z3-solver, this problem is resolved.

Comment: I have checked that both z3 and z3-solver have to be installed (in Pycharm IDE) in order to solve the AttributeError

Answer (score 0):

The `z3` package is likely not imported correctly. Make sure you are in the right environment when executing the Python code.